# Is PA complete when multiplication is bounded?

Tags: arithmetic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

Working in PA.

Fix some natural number "$n"$.

> Is PA complete for sentences that do not use  the symbol $``\times"$ unless all of their variables are bounded $< n$.

Comment: I am not sure, but since the Presburg arithmetic is known to be consistent and complete, this should also be the case for PA with multiplication only for bounded numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, a much stronger fact holds. Say that a formula $\varphi$ of arithmetic is **multiplicatively bounded** if for every term $t$ of the form $t_1\times t_2$ for $t_1,t_2$ terms which occurs in $\varphi$, every variable occurring in $t$ is within the scope of a bounded quantifier with bound a variable-free term. So e.g. if $\theta(x,y,z)$ is quantifier-free and the variable $y$ doesn't occur in any multiplicand in $\theta$ then the sentence $$\forall x<\underline{7}\forall y\exists z<\underline{120}[\theta(x,y,z)]$$ is multiplicatively bounded.

Then:

> $\mathsf{PA}$ proves every true multiplicatively bounded sentence.

The point is that we can computably transform each multiplicatively bounded $\varphi$ into a $\mathsf{PA}$-provably-equivalent $\hat{\varphi}$ which does not use "$\times$" simply by enumerating all the finitely many possibilities for the relevant variables, and then appeal to Presburger arithmetic. For example, if $\theta$ is as above we have $$\forall x<\underline{7}\forall y\exists z<\underline{120}[\theta(x,y,z)]\quad\equiv\quad\bigwedge_{i<7}[\forall y\bigvee_{j<120}(\theta(\underline{i}, y,\underline{j}))],$$ and all terms of the form "$t_1\times t_2$" inside $\theta(\underline{i}, y,\underline{j})$ are now varaible-free and so can be replaced with numerals. The result is a sentence of the form $$\bigwedge_{i<7}\forall y\bigvee_{j<120}\eta_{i,j}(y),$$ where for each $i<7,j<120$ the formula $\eta_{i,j}$ is $\times$-free. The equivalence between this formula and the original one is provable in $\mathsf{PA}$, as is this new formula itself (being a consequence of Presburger arithmetic).

(And as usual, $\mathsf{PA}$ here is overkill - Presburger arithmetic plus Robinson arithmetic is already enough.)

Comment: And unsurprisingly, we can broaden the definition of "multiplicatively bounded." Take a formula $\varphi$ where for simplicity no variable occurs bound by two quantifiers. Define the set of *ultimately explicitly bounded variables* to be the smallest set $S$ of bounded variables in $\varphi$ such that every variable introduced by a quantifier of the form "$\forall x<t$" or "$\exists x<t$" with $t$ a term only using variables in $S$ is in $S$ (this is recursive). Then the above argument applies to all formulas in which every variable appearing in a multiplicand is ultimately explicitly bounded.